# Looking for a term for a (possibly) disregarded attempt (in sports)

Tags: word-request

Trying to translate a sports software I have a hard time finding a word or term for an attempt that does not (necessarily) count - As in: you have 3 attempts, but only the 2 better ones count towards the result/ ranking - the other one is scratched. How do you call that scratched attempt?

I tried translating the German word with google and bing - but the translations are sure not what I need... "Streichwert" -> "spreading worth" (google) is nonsense and "Stroke value" (bing) ... does not sound right either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe a single word exists. The google and bing suggestions are garbage, and come from splitting the word into components and translating each one. The word is not found in common online German-English dictionaries.

You can used "discarded score" or (as you have already suggested) "disregarded score".  If the system discards both the top and the bottom scores (as is done in diving competition) you can say "trimmed mean" for the average, ignoring the top and bottom results.

In context "discard" is enough (the fact it is a score being clear from context). To emulate the layout at http://www.reinickendorfermgc.de/Ergebnisse/TTL171.pdf

```
name       score
Team Rockets 11
Hans          4
Rolf          2   
Fritz         7
Discard       2
```

Similarly a rule set could state "The two lowest scores will be discarded", or "The final score is the sum of the top three attempts." thereby avoiding the need for a noun that means "discarded score".

Since this word isn't yet in German English dictionaries, I would guess it is a fairly modern coinage.

Comment: Dropped/Scratched/Discarded all sound good - how would you call the number of "discardable attempts" (before the competition)?

Comment: edited to address this. Rather than saying "The number of discardable attempts is two", say "up to two attempts are discardable" or some paraphrase.

Answer (score 2):

The lowest score, the one that is *streichwuerdig* in your case, once it has been disregarded could be called the *stricken score* or the *scratched score*.  But there's no one simple noun that refers to an uncounted item that has been ignored because only the two best scores are counted.

Answer (score 1):

The other two answers have fine suggestions (*discarded/stricken/scratched.*)  One other possibility is *dropped.*

- *Each jumper has three attempts.  Rankings are based on the average of the best two attempts.  In the case of a perfect tie, the **dropped score** is used as a tie-breaker.*
- *"That guy dominated the whole field today.  His **dropped** score was higher than anyone else's keepers."*

This terminology is also very common in [class syllabi](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&q=syllabus%20drop%20%22lowest%20scores%22)

- *You will be able to **drop** your two lowest scores (a missed quiz is a zero). Save these **dropped quizzes** for emergencies.*  <sub>source: [WSU Math 106 sylabus](http://math.wsu.edu/math/faculty/cjacobs/106/106syllabus.pdf)</sub>

If both the top and bottom are discarded, the average of the remaining scores is referred to as the [*modified mean* or *Olympic average.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_mean#Terminology)

Comment: Dropped/Scratched/Discarded all sound good - how would you call the number of "droppable attempts" (before the competition)?

Comment: @FrankB I would call them _"dropped _____s"_  (_dropped scores, dropped throws, dropped grades, dropped runs_ etc.)